# using const in this code

Tags: c++, constants

this code compiled and executed well without using const.
Is there a special reason for using const in here?

```
0   #include <iostream>
1   using namespace std;
2
3   int sum(const int array[], const int length) {
4     long sum = 0;
5     for(int i = 0; i < length; sum += array[i++]);
6     return sum;
7   }
8
9   int main() {
10    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
11    cout << "Sum: " << sum(arr, 7) << endl;
12    return 0;
13  }
```

- code reference: MIT C++ Open Course Lecture Note 4 "Arrays and Strings"
- URL: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-096-introduction-to-c-january-iap-2011/lecture-notes/MIT6_096IAP11_lec04.pdf

Comment: Better question: "this code compiled and executed well with const,  is there a special reason for not using const here?".

Comment: @JonathanDursi: Not a duplicate, because there's no parameter of form `const T xx[]`, only `const T` asked about.

Comment: @Deduplicator : I see the argument, but the answers given to that question specifically bring up issues like pointers, references, etc.  There's no reason for this question to stand on its own, although there may certainly be a better dup suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

You use `const` to achive `const`-correctness.  This means you've told the compiler (and any reader of your code) all the things that *don't* change in themselves or objects they work on.  You *have* done this for the args to `sum`, correctly saying that they aren't changed in the function.  The reason why you bother to do this is because it maskes the code easier to reason about (for the reader) and opens up optimisation possibilities (for the compiler).

Comment: And allows passing an array of `const int`. (Top-level qualifiers of function arguments are not part of the function declaration, but only the definition, see `length`. And in this case qualifiers can be added on  assignment to the argument)

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of purpose behind the first const, no real need for the second one.

It would compile without const but try this function:

```
int inc(const int array[], const int length) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
       ++array[i];
}
```

and your code should not compile.

Remove the first `const` and it will.

This shows you the purpose of the first `const`. Promises not to mutate the data.

Conversely, try changing the calling function:

```
int main() 
{
   const int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
   cout << "Sum: " << sum(arr, 7) << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Now if you try compiling `sum()` without the first `const` you will get a compiler error because you cannot convert `arr` to a non-const array (essentially pointer).

However even though 7 is a constant, you can still remove the second const in function `sum` as it is passed by value.

Answer (score 1):

```
int sum(const int array[], const int length) {/* ... */}
```

While the first `const` is not top-level (`array` is of type unqualified pointer to `const int`), the second one is.

Thus, the second one is relevant to the *function definition*, it does not change the *function declaration* at all, and should thus be left out of a pure declaration as extraneous noise.

*Equivalent **declarations***:

```
int sum(const int* array, int length); // Removed synatactic sugar and useless const
int sum(const int* const array, const int length); // Added top-level const
```

Building on the first part, the reasons for the two `const` are completely different:

- The reason for `const`-qualifying `length` is the exact same as for any local variable: Avoiding inadvertant changes, by directly changing it or inadvertantly passing it to a modifying function.
- The reason for `const`-qualifying the element type of the pointer `array` (array-notation used for clarifying that it is intended to be an array), is guaranteeing to the caller that the elements wont be changed. That allows passing pointer to both `const`-qualified and un-qualified `int`s.

Answer (score 0):

The first `const` promises to never change the array. For the code you've posted it doesn't make a difference. But imagine that `arr` had been declared in `main` as `int const arr[]` instead. The function as written would still work, but without the `const` it wouldn't, despite never changing the array.

The `const` before `length` however doesn't change the interface of the function. It just causes the local argument variable `length` to be unchangeable. This can be a safeguard if you indeed don't want to change `length` in the implementation (because the compiler will flag any change of `length` as error).

Answer (score 0):

There are two qualifiers const in the function declaration

```
int sum(const int array[], const int length);
```

In fact the second const qualifier does not have any special meaning for using the function. These two function declarations

```
int sum(const int array[], const int length);

int sum(const int array[], int length);
```

declare the same one function. This const only plays a role within the body of the function.

As for the first const qualifier then it allows to use constant arrays with this function. For example consider your code with the following array definition

```
const int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```